# System user write permissions to samba share

Tags: server, permissions, mount, samba

For the life of me I can't figure this out.

I have a NAS (Netgear ReadyNAS) sharing an open/guest Samba share. Anonymous access is allowed, no user restrictions. I can connect and read/write to the share via Windows.

My Ubuntu server can also mount it, I can write to it as root, but my system user (qbt-nox) I have setup for qBittorrent cannot.

qBitorrent can write (ie download) to its home directory. If I mount the SMB share to its home directory, no dice.

Here's my fstab

```
//192.168.11.6/media /home/qbt-nox/nas cifs guest,uid=1111,gid=113 0 0
```

And the permissions when mounted

```
drwxr-xr-x 2 1111 qbt-nox 0 June 28 00:29 nas
```

Top

```
  PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND


1343 qbt-nox   20   0 1164352 124532  18336 S   0.0  6.5   1:46.00 qbittorrent-nox
```

What am I missing?

Comment: What does gid113 mean? I'd expect something like gid=113. gid is the group id of the local user, so it needs to be the group id of the user that runs bittorrent

Comment: Sorry, fixed. It is gid=113. I didn't copy and paste because I'm using HyperV to manage and not SSH.

Comment: What user and group is qBittorent running as?

Comment: top:

1343 qbt-nox   20   0 1164352 124532  18336 S   0.0  6.5   1:45.94 qbittorrent-nox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I admit I do not understand this fstab entry:

> //192.168.11.6/media /home/qbt-nox/nas cifs guest,uid=1111,gid=113 0 0

I do not understand who 1111 is and what relationship that user has to 113. Since this is a guest accessible share I would just open it up to everyone on your local Linux box:

```
//192.168.11.6/media /home/qbt-nox/nas cifs guest,uid=1111,gid=113,nounix,dir_mode=0777,file_mode=0666 0 0
```

I kept the uid / gid specification in there just in case something requires it but the above should make it read / write to every local user.

You can modify dir_mode / file_mode to ... for example 0775 / 0664 if you only want this 1111 user you speak of and the group user 113 to have write access and everyone else read.

Comment: Thank you! That did it. 1111/113 is the system user/group I created to run the torrent service (so it isn't running as root).